# Enabling all buttons in a repeater except for the clicked one

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, repeater

I have a `Repeater Control` with various buttons in it.

When the button gets clicked, it needs to disable itself so it cant be clicked again. **Working.**

However, when I click that button, it needs to enable any other button but it.

So, When I click on it, it needs to disable. When I click on another one, the previous button must enable, and that one must disable.

So for I've tried:

```
Button btnLoad = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnLoad");

foreach (Button b in e.Item.Controls.OfType<Button>().Select(c => c).Where(b => b != btnLoad))
{
   b.Enabled = true;
}

btnLoad.Text = "Currently Viewing";
btnLoad.Enabled = false;
```

But it isnt working. Depending on where I put it, its either leaving all the buttons enabled (But still changing its text), or not doing anything at all.

What do I need to do to make this work?

**Edit:** The code is found here:

`protected void rptPdfList_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)`

Which is why I use `Button btnLoad = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnLoad");`.

The method is found in :

```
switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "LoadDoc":
                 //Above code
               break;
        }
```

Comment: Where is that code located?

Comment: :/ forgot to add where it was... Adding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want that code in the `Button`'s `Click`-event handler:

```
protected void Button_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button thisButton = (Button) sender;
    thisButton.Text = "Currently Viewing";
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) thisButton.NamingContainer;
    IEnumerable<Button> buttons = item.Controls.OfType<Button>();
    foreach(var btn in buttons)
    {
        btn.Enabled = btn != thisButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the lack of insight my part. I've updated my question.

Comment: The previous buttons still arent enabling - they are remaining in a disabled state.

Comment: @NewAmbition: With the code above or with your `ItemCommand`? Are you databinding the repeater on postbacks somewhere?

Comment: `ItemCommand`.... The repeater has to populate on page load, although its in an `AjaxUpdatePanel`

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple if statement in a loop as below

```
Button btnLoad = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnLoad");
foreach (Control c in e.Item.Controls)
    {
        if (b is Button)
        {
            if(b == btnLoad)
             {
             b.Enabled = false;
             }
            else
             {
             b.Enabled = true;
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: In my code, I've changed your loop into a Linq statement.. Same thing really :/